# How to click button on web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, bots

I'm making a bot in program "atom" using javascript (extensions chrome) and want to click button "add to cart". My html is `<input type = "submit" name = "commit" value = "add to cart" class = "button">`. I guess I need to do this when using value. how to do it?

Comment: `document.getElementsByName('commit')[0].click()`

Comment: I think it should be:
document.querySelector ('input [value = "add to cart"]');
just don't know how to complete the syntax

Comment: I deleted my answer as it did not properly address your issue. Hopefully someone can provide a better solution.